# How do I create a Clock variable - java.time

Tags: java, datetime

I'm using the following package: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

How do I create a clock variable? I tried:

```java
Clock clock = new Clock();
```

But I got the error:

> TimeCheck.java:14: error: Clock is abstract; cannot be instantiated

I also tried private Clock clock; outside of the main() function, but when I ran the main() function and tried clock.instant() it said:

> TimeCheck.java:16: error: non-static variable clock cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: There are a ton of factory methods in the doc you linked to.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: What kind of `Clock` do you want specifically? How do you want the `Clock` to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *java.time* classes automatically use a default `Clock` object.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;  // Default `Clock` used implicitly.
```

You only need to obtain a `Clock` if you want altered behavior. Typically that would be for testing or demonstration.

The *java.time* framework eschews the use of `new`. Look for factory methods instead.

Look at the static methods on the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class. You will find methods to give you various clocks with altered cadence, or fixed to a specific moment, or continually operating with a delay.

```
Clock fixedClock = Clock.fixed( Instant.EPOCH , ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
Instant nowFake = Instant.now( fixedClock ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful